# How to call a javascript function after an async postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I was using the following script to call a javascript function only if my page in Edit Mode:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (EditMode)
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript("".GetType(), 
                                           "EnableSelectableKey", 
                                           "EnableSelectableForRolesLists();",
                                            true);
}
```

After I added an update panel, the script has not been called.

How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx

This should point you in the right direction :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but that link has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Pretty sure it does. See the answer by Jamie Treworgy which also references the exact same technique as a possible solution and provides an alternative. Answer is also accepted...

Answer (score 5):

Using `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.endRequest` as Dave_Stott says is a cleaner way to do this (if there is such a thing as "clean" when talking about `UpdatePanels` and client/server interaction). But you can also simply change your code to use `ScriptManager` instead of `ClientScript` and it should work:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript("".GetType(), 
                                           "EnableSelectableKey", 
                                           "EnableSelectableForRolesLists();",
                                            true);
```